# Should I always remove Firebase listener in viewDidDisappear()?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For the main page of my app, which is like Facebook's newsfeed, I am following David East's advice to add listener in `viewWillAppear()` and remove it in `viewDidDisappear()` (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/best-practices-for-ios-uiviewcontroller_6.html). Doing so, I have to clear my data model array and reload the collection view in `viewDidDisappear()`, otherwise duplicates will be loaded when the view appears again and the listener is reattached. This causes the page to be blank for noticeable amount of time, whenever user comes back to the main page.

Given that users will spend most time on the main page, I just wonder is it absolutely necessary to remove the listener? If so, what are good ways to handle it to prevent blank page?

Also, as a side question, where should I add my notification listener (to listen to events such as friend request)? I assume they should be on all the time and shouldn't be associated to any view controllers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one-size-fits-all advice here. In fact, what you have here is a classical speed-vs-size trade-off.

If you think the additional memory usage outweighs the bandwidth+time you'd incur otherwise, then you're free to leave the listeners attached while the main page is not showing. Just make sure to then *not* attach additional listeners when the user comes back to the main page.

Comment: Thanks as always, Frank!